# How to pass in a different config file when running a stellar quickstart docker container?

Tags: stellar-core, docker, stellar.toml

The Stellar quickstart contains a config file at stellar/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg which it uses by default to start stellar core once the container is first run.

How can do a first run of the stellar core using another tailor-made config file for our production instance of stellar core with the configurations required?

Is there a way to pass in another config file to be used when executing the `docker run` command on the container?

In other words, a way to pass in the configuration file from the host (instead of running `stellar-core run --conf betterfile.cfg` inside the container)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can enter the docker container with `docker exec -it stellar /bin/bash`
2. Then enter `supervisorctl`
3. and then enter `stop stellar-core`. This will stop stellar-core.
4. Enter `exit` to exit supervisor.
5. Then edit the stellar-core.cfg file in the base directory of the docker container.
6. Type `supervisorctl` again and type `start stellar-core`

Comment: Thanks. Does this method also work for the other config files for the Horizon, Postgresql or Supervisor services? e.g. stopping and starting horizon with edits to the `horizon.env` file?

Comment: Yes it does work for all of them

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mount your config file to the container 
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

So you can try to do something like
`docker run -v myconfigfile.cfg /path/to/config/file/in/container`

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully customized our `stellar-core` configuration by following the documentation of https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/

> To customize the configurations that both stellar-core and horizon use, you must use persistent mode. The default configurations will be copied into the data directory upon launching a persistent mode container for the first time.
>
> …
>
> It is recommended that you stop the container before editing any of these files, then restart the container after completing your customization.